# mat Sidenavbar not showing in angular v17. Not getting any error but still sidenav also not showing

Tags: angular

I have implemented mat sidenavbar. I am using angular v17 i have created a sidenavbar component and trying to display that by calling it in app component. I have getting no error in console but getting blank screen when trying to display sidenavbar.

I want to display sidenavbar to the left and based on the selection show components to the right side

Comment: Could you please share some code or create a StackBlitz URL? So that we can look at the problem in your code and try to resolve it,.

Comment: i have added provideAnimations() too but still nothing is coming.

Comment: https://create-nqiid7.stackblitz.io

Comment: i have added all in this stackblitz but i am trying it in v17 stackblitz is showing in v5.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-17-file-upload-dxrtn7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
You can update this StackBlitz . because what you have shared is not working anyways.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Rabina you have no CSS for your mat-side-nav. Make the sidenav absolute over your pages high an width, then you should get your nav back

Comment: @Ｒの卄ＩＴ i have added my code in the link you shared but it has app.module.ts , i dont have that and in app.config.ts i have added provideAnimations().

Comment: @Marlon i have added css still its same. No change. You can check the link provided by Rohit

Comment: i tried to set the background-color and it showed , my fault i did not add anything relevant in the html. After adding html and background-color it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tried to set the background-color and it showed , my fault i did not add anything relevant in the html. After adding html and background-color it worked.

Comment: Please, close the question if you find the answer by yourself